# MSSQL Nodejs Streaming is not waiting to finish to Return

Tags: node.js, sql-server, asynchronous, async-await, stream

This is my first time dealing with streams and I am stuck. I am using the `mssql` NodeJS package.

I have these functions below to upsert very large data. For each region, I get the data from SQL Server and for each 10000 lines upsert to Mongo.

The problem is, `_refreshArsenalData` function will not wait for the `sqlService.refreshArsenal` function to finish, so it will return undefined. I tried making `sqlService.refreshArsenal` async and awaiting it but it seems like it didn't change anything.

What am I doing wrong?

```
async function _refreshArsenalData({ orgId }, ctx) {

  const lastUpdate = await dataService.getLastUpdate(orgId)
  
  const regions = await dataService.getRegions(orgId)

  await asyncForEach(regions, async (region ) => {

    const query = sqlService.getQueryForRefreshArsenal(region, lastUpdate)

    let { upsertedCount, matchedCount } = await sqlService.refreshArsenal(query, orgId)

    return {upsertedCount, matchedCount}
  })
}

async function asyncForEach(array: any, callback: any) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
}
```

SQL SERVICE

```
refreshArsenal = async (query: string, orgId: string) => {

    let upsertedCount = 0
    let matchedCount = 0

    await sql.connect(config.sqlConnection, async (err: any) => {
      const request = new sql.Request()
      
      request.stream = true
      request.query(query)

      let rowsToProcess: any[] = []
      
      request.on(`row`, async (row: any) => {
        rowsToProcess.push(row)

        if (rowsToProcess.length >= 10000) {
          request.pause();
          let { matched, upserted } = await bulkUpsertMongo();
          upsertedCount += upserted
          matchedCount += matched
        }
      })

      request.on(`done`, async () => {
        if (rowsToProcess.length) {
          let { matched, upserted } = await bulkUpsertMongo();
          upsertedCount += upserted
          matchedCount += matched
        }
      })

      sql.on(`error`, () => {
        throw new Error(err.toString())
      })


      async function bulkUpsertMongo() {

        let ops: any[] = []
        for (const row of rowsToProcess) {
          ops.push({
            updateOne: {
              filter: { rnc_regid: row.rnc_regid },
              update: { $set: row },
              upsert: true
            },
          })
        }
        const result = await bulkUpsert(ops, orgId)

        rowsToProcess = []
        request.resume()
        return { matched: result.matchedCount, upserted: result.upsertedCount }
      }
    })
    return { upsertedCount, matchedCount }
}
```

Comment: refreshArsenal code executes regardless of event `row` or `done`, and returns data, you need to ensure that it returns only after all the data has been processed. probably you could use `done` event to finalize returning data.

Comment: Well, I tried everything I can think of but nothing changed. It returns undefined objects right now. If what you said was the problem, it would return 0 values, right? @HarshVishwakarma

Comment: yes, I can't think of another reason without running the code